# Multidex not working only in AndroidTest

Tags: android, integration-testing, dex

I have a project that has MultiDex and it compiles the app just fine... But when I try to run the instrumented tests I get this error:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForMinApi16StagingDebugAndroidTest'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

I am using

testInstrumentationRunner 'com.android.test.runner.MultiDexTestRunner'

In my gradle file.

How can I make the multdex work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case for any one looking for a answer to this. It is not currently possible to use multidex in the API 19 and lower with AGP 3.0.0 you can track the issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37324038

Answer (score 1):

Multidex on KitKat isn't very well supported. There are support libraries that allow you to run your multidexed Android app on KitKat but those can't help you when your `androidTest` APK is also multidexed. I wrote more about it in [this blog post](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/07/16/support-kitkat-multidex/) so I could remember how to solve this in the future for other apps.

I'm not sure if it is the exact problem that you're experiencing, but I hope it helps you in some way.

In addition to this, there appears to be others that have a similar problem to the one you're describing. Have you tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43885288/6858264)?